When to use de + verb when the verb is nominalized
This question is specifically about whether to use de with verbs when the verb is like a noun.
Consider the following two English sentences:

Having a good friend is having a treasure in life
Having a good friend is not the same as having a treasure in life

When translating, I came up with the following:

Avoir un bon ami c'est avoir un trésor dans la vie 
Avoir un bon ami c'est pas le même que avoir un trésor dans la vie

Then, I was told that I was wrong, and a de was needed, so I made the changes:

D'avoir un bon ami c'est d'avoir un trésor dans la vie 
D'avoir un bon ami c'est pas le même que d'avoir un trésor dans la vie

Now, the que d'avoir feels really off for me, but I can't explain why. I can't explain if I needed the de in front of verbs, and if not always, then under what circumstances. Could someone please explain to me when nominalizing verbs, should I, or when should I, add the de in front of the infinitive ? Thanks !

Who told you Avoir un bon ami c'est avoir un trésor dans la vie was wrong? Because it is absolutely correct. (Whereas I don't expect any French native to say D'avoir un bon ami c'est d'avoir un trésor dans la vie, for me it is wrong). Your other sentence is wrong, but not because it should need de, it should be c'est pas la même chose qu'avoir un trésor dans la vie. What is correct is that in some cases the phrase c'est pas la même chose que can be followed by de+infinitive.

D'avoir un bon ami... is at least not correct. I would also add that Avoir un bon ami... is not terribly good style, it's lourd in my opinion. I would prefer "Un bon ami, c'est un trésor dans la vie.

@Frank I think you miss the point. I would have much to say about the English example "Having a good friend is having a treasure in life" and it would all be off-topic.

@FrançoisJurain I'm commenting around the point, that is certainly not missed.

@None It was Google Docs actually, underlining my sentence in blue and telling me to add de ...

Having de before the infinitive has got nothing to do with the fact that the word is an infinitive (nominalised or not), it entirely depends on the construction.
When the infinitive acts as a subject:

Avoir un bon ami c'est avoir un trésor dans la vie.1
Lire me détend.

there's no way we could have de is front of the infinitive.
When the infinitive acts as an attribute we don't have de if the subject is an infinitive:

Avoir un bon ami c'est avoir un trésor pour la vie.1

but if the subject is not an infinitive, then we need de:

Ma chance c'est d'avoir un ami.

La préposition de après que dans les comparaisons avec un verbe à l’infinitif (BDL):
Que is sometimes used to establish a comparison between two elements, in expressions such as autant... que, il vaut mieux... que, préférer... plutôt que, etc. If it precedes a verb in the infinitive, que can be followed by the preposition de. However, this is optional.

Avoir un ami c'est la même chose (c'est pareil) qu'avoir un trésor pour la vie. Avoir un ami c'est la même chose (c'est pareil) que d'avoir un trésor pour la vie. Both can be said.

J'aime mieux lire que jouer aux jeux vidéos. J'aime mieux lire que de jouer aux jeux vidéos.  Both can be said.



1 I agree with @Frank's comment that this construction can sound clumsy but it is grammatically correct.

Thanks, but you said "but if the attribute is not an infinitive, then we need de:", did you perhaps mean "but if the subject is not an infinitive, then we need de:" ? If not, I might not have understood you

@dvx2718 Quite right! You understood perfectly,  my bad. Rectified.
